# What order the test cases run in the tSQLt?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, sql-server-2012, tdd, tsqlt

I have 30 test cases in the 'EmployeeSchema'. I want to know in which order the test cases run in the tSqlt? If I know the order of execution of test cases, then I alter the execution order of my test cases one after another. Kindly advise.

```
-- Runs all the tests on MyTestClass
EXEC tSQLt.Run 'EmployeeSchema';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running all tests within a test class, `tSQLt.Run` will run the tests in "random" order, meaning `tSQLt` leaves the order up to SQL Server and how it retrieves the data.  Although, it shouldn't matter which order they run in since each test should be independent in and of itself.

If for some reason you want to run individual tests in a different order you will need to run `tSQLt.Run` separately for each individual test in whichever order you want.  You can't specify a particular order when you call `tSQLt.Run` for an entire test class.

Note: thanks to @Sebastian Meine for correcting me

To confirm it is <strike>random</strike> execution plan dependent, here is the cursor declaration from `tSQLt.Private_RunTestClass` that pulls the list of tests within the requested test class.  There is no `ORDER BY` so SQL Server will return the test names in whichever order it sees fit.

```
DECLARE testCases CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD 
    FOR
 SELECT tSQLt.Private_GetQuotedFullName(object_id)
   FROM sys.procedures
  WHERE schema_id = @TestClassId
    AND LOWER(name) LIKE 'test%';
```

Comment: This is incorrect. tSQLt executes test cases in random order. (It did alphabetical ordering at some point in the past, though the documentation always talked about random order.)

Comment: Oh ugh, you're right.  I just looked through the code and it does not include an ordering so it definitely would run in random order as per anything with no ORDER BY.  Thanks for that!  Updated my answer.

Comment: I ran test runs of several test classes I have and they all came back in alphabetic order so I made that (incorrect) assumption...

Comment: So "not guaranteed" and "execution plan dependent" rather than actually randomised then. If the execution plan has a seek on `sys.sysschobjs.nc1` and lookups then the likelihood is that they will probably be ordered by name as that is `nsclass, nsid, name` and it does an equality on the two leading columns. Random would imply some deliberate shuffling with `ORDER BY NEWID()` or similar

Comment: I made this change quite a while ago but it is possible that it didn’t make it into a release yet: https://github.com/tSQLt-org/tSQLt/blob/383e1aa7de2c42cc1b67ead86055268c523ef196/Source/Run_Methods.sql#L411  —— however, we will release the newest version tomorrow and that will contain the deliberate random order. Either way, order was never guaranteed, as there never was an explicit fixed order implemented.

Comment: @SebastianMeine Thanks for that info.  FWIW, I'm using the latest version provided with RedGate SQL Test.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for that explanation.  I didn't know exactly what SQL Server does when no ORDER BY is used.  I knew it wasn't exactly random, but not precisely what the strategy is.

Comment: @squillman, SQL Server is reading the data in the most convenient way, if no `ORDER BY` is specified. That often leads to the rows being returned in the order of the clustered index particularly when you're testing things. But on a busy server several optimization techniques (e.g piggyback reading) can lead to out-of-order processing. — In other words, without an `ORDER BY`, there are no guarantees as to the order. Rows will be returned in unexpected ways at the most inconvenient times. (edited for clarity)

Comment: @SebastianMeine Yeah, I get that at a high level.  I know that there's no guaranteed order unless specified with `ORDER BY`.  I'm just not up to speed on the internals and what exactly happens when if it's not specified.  I figured that cluster index order would be part of the equation at times but have never dug deeper.  Thanks for the info! :)